# Do not hardcode "/data/"; use Context.getFilesDir().getPath() instead

Tags: android, sqlite, android-assets

I need to copy my database from Assets folder to "/data/data/com.example.provadatabase/databases/"

i was using this code

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.provadatabase/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "MN1";
```

and then create a database if not exist then it should copy into the created database the database from assets

```
InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

myOutput.flush();
myOutput.close();
myInput.close();

}
```

The database is well created but it doesen't copy my database to databases folder and the code give this warning "Do not hardcode "/data/"; use Context.getFilesDir().getPath() instead"

What should i use to copy my db?

Comment: I don't understand. `use Context.getFilesDir().getPath()` what more do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what the error tells you to do.

```
String outFileName = context.getDatabasePath(DatabaseHelper.DB_NAME).getParentFile() + DB_NAME;
```

This assumes that context is available, which it usually is in the constructor. But honestly, I would just use [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

Comment: In such a way DB won't be placed under `/databases/` folder

Comment: It still doesent copy the db in databases folder

Comment: Follow the last advice, use SQLiteAssetHelper. It manages all this for you.

Comment: i have importended SQliteAssetHelper, then?

Comment: Follow the instructions there. They are better than anything I'd tell you.